# Unable to order by multiple columns and seeing different responses of the same query on django shell and via ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am writing a simple chatting feature for a booking application where a `customer` can send messages to an `owner` and `owner` can reply to those messages. Also an `owner` can be a `customer` as well.

I am storing those messages in a table which is created by this model -

```
class CustomerOwnerMessages(BaseModel):

    message = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name="message_from_customer",
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name="message_to_owner",
    )
```

My task is to get the list of `customers` who has so far exchanged the messages with the logged in `owner`.

1. Let say the `pk` of that `owner` is `1`. So first I planned to get the object of `User` model like this -

```
owner = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

2. Then I decided to get all the messages of this user sent or received as an owner from model `CustomerOwnerMessages`. Please note that I have defined `related_name` for each foreign key in the same model.

```
messages = owner.message_to_owner.filter()
```

3. I have the list of all the instances of  `messages` sent by this `owner`. Now I just want the list of all the unique instances where the combination `(owner, customer)` isn't repeated. So I decided to order_by the messages like this -

```
active_chats = messages.order_by('owner', 'customer')
```

***Problem 1 -***

The problem with these lines of code is if I run this via Django's shell then I get the queryset as a response but the response is not ordered by `("customer", "owner")` instead I get all the instances of `CustomerOwnerMessages` where `owner=1`.

***Problem 2 -***

Then I also run this via `ListAPIView` -

```
 def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id).message_from_customer.filter().order_by("customer", "owner")
```

The response of this queryset by `ListAPIView` an error -

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'message_from_customer'
```

Am I on the right track? Where have I been going wrong to see this weir issues?

Comment: `User.objects.filter` will return a `UserQueryset` which does not have `message_from_customer`, try using `get` instead of `filter`. 

Or, you can simply do `self.request.user.message_from_customer.filter().order_by("customer", "owner")`

Comment: This doesn't work!